# how to resolve error while creating first AWS Lamda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to create First Lambda function , i have got the access as "PowerUserAccess" . and its a new console . i am  getting  error as:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::387035554709:user/Sulabh@myemail.com is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::387035554709:role/service-role/getListTest-role-9d7tzpx3 because no identity-based policy allows the iam:CreateRole action
```

[image]

how can i resolve this error? and create first lambda function?
also do i need to create Application first to add lambda functions inside that?

Answer (score 0):

PowerUserAccess can not create IAM roles/policies. Contact with admin or login as Admin and follow the instructions below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html